# PostgreSQL Database - Error Assistance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query that will update the value of `rgn_no` and `chp_cd` within the table `bue` to the values of `rgn_no` and `chp_cd` within the table `chapterassociation`. I don't think the WHERE clause is any problems, but I'm getting the following error when I run it in:

SQL error:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "bue" violates foreign key constraint "bue_chp_cd_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (chp_cd)=(CA3) is not present in table "chapter".
```

---

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

SQL Query:

```sql
UPDATE bue SET
 rgn_no = chapterassociation.rgn_no,
 chp_cd = chapterassociation.chp_cd
FROM
 chapterassociation
WHERE
 bue.mbr_no IS NULL AND bue.chp_cd IS NULL
 AND bue.work_state = chapterassociation.work_state
 AND bue.bgu_cd = chapterassociation.bgu_cd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error message:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "bue" violates foreign key constraint
"bue_chp_cd_fkey" DETAIL: Key (chp_cd)=(CA3) is not present in table "chapter".
```

It says that one of your updates wants to set chp_cd to 'CA3', but that CA3 is not an allowed value, because a foreign key constraint wants the value 'CA3" to be present in the table "chapter". That's all.

There is nothing wrong with your query's syntax, it is just the fact that your query would cause the data to conflict with a constraint in the data model.